# How to Use ROW_NUMBER OVER() in SQL

Tags: numbers, row, clickhouse

Struggling to understand the implementation of `ROW_NUMBER()` `OVER()` in SQL? Can someone help me understand how to efficiently assign row numbers to query results?

Can I use `count()` to get the total number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a function that assigns a unique row number to each row within a partition of a result set.

Say you have a table of Employees with columns `FirstName` and `LastName` and `Salary`. `ROW_NUMBER()` is used to assign a unique row number to each row in the result set. The `OVER` clause determines how the row numbers are assigned. In this case, it’s ordering by Salary in descending order. So, the employee with the highest salary will have a row number of 1, the next highest will have a row number of 2, and so on.

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Salary,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM 
    Employees
```

This is a sample table output for the same example

```
  FirstName    LastName   Salary    RowNumber
  John         Doe        80000     1
  Jane         Smith      75000     2
  Mike         Johnson    70000     3
  Emily        Davis      65000     4
```